# Display content at specific day and time

Tags: php

I'd like to show some content on Monday - Friday between 09:00 and 17:00.  This is what I have so far but it's not working.

```
$current_time = idate('H');
$current_day = idate('w');

// Daytime - weekdays between 9am - 5pm
if ($current_day >= 0 || $current_day <= 4 && $current_time >= 9 || $current_time <= 17 ) {
        // do something
    }
```

Comment: When using `||` and `&&` inside an if, it is usually better to use brackets

Comment: `if ( ( $current_day >= 0 || $current_day <= 4 ) && ( $current_time >= 9 || $current_time <= 17 ) ) {` ~ use braces inside to separate the conditions

Answer (score 0):

Should be `&&` as you want all of them to be `true`. **Daytime - weekdays between 9am - 5pm**

```
if ($current_day >= 0 && $current_day <= 4 && $current_time >= 9 && $current_time <= 17 )
```